# Why are some system defined with the name "variable mass"?

Tags: momentum, conservation-laws

I do not get why system such as the rocket in space are defined as "variable mass" since **the mass of the system is not varying**.

The equation used for such systems $$\sum F^{(E)}=\frac{d\vec{P}}{dt} \tag{1}$$ (sum of external forces on the system equals the change in momentum) holds true only if the **total mass of the system** does not change during the time interval $dt$ considered. Is this correct? I'm not sure of what I'm saying, only supposing it, because in the proof for $(1)$ on textbook the center of mass is used and the mass of the system  is taken as constant in the derivatives.

Does the mass **of the system** really increase or decrease and $(1)$ holds true also if the mass of the system is varying?

Comment: The mass is changing. Instead of a continuous rocket engine, think about two masses connected by a spring. Initially the two masses are moving together, i.e. the momentum is $P_{total}=(m_1+m_2)v$. When you let them go, the two masses will be moving apart, each having its own velocity, so the total momentum will now be $P_{total}=m_1v_1+m_2v_2$. One can't talk about the total mass any longer, instead we have to consider the two masses independently. For the case of the rocket the rocket's mass keeps decreasing continuously until the fuel runs out.

Comment: @CuriousOne I don't see why the system cannot be considered as composed of both the two masses anymore. Momentum is conserved for the **whole** system, not for the two singular masses in that case.

Comment: The two masses are not moving at the same velocity and, you are right, the momentum of the different parts of the system is not conserved, only the total is. The center of mass of a rocket never moves, but the individual parts do. What you are trying to calculate is the motion of the individual parts.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not get why system such as the rocket in space are defined as "variable mass" since the mass of the system is not varying.

This depends entirely on where one draws the system boundaries. One possible boundary is the rocket plus all of the exhaust gases it has released. The center of mass of the rocket + exhaust gas cloud system moves per the external forces exerted on the system. Internal forces such as the rocket ejecting exhaust mass plays no role in the behavior of this system.

This is not a very useful system boundary. Since the exhaust gases leave the rocket at supersonic speeds, the only interaction between the rocket itself and the exhaust cloud it has left behind is gravitation. This force is negligibly small. More importantly, when people launch a spacecraft into space, and then Mars or beyond, those people want to know where the rocket is. The location of the center of mass of the constant mass system comprising the rocket and the exhaust cloud the rocket has left behind is not a quantity of interest. Nobody bothers to calculate that quantity.

> The equation used for such systems [is] $\sum F_\text{ext} = \frac {d\vec P}{dt}$.

There is no difference between $\vec F = m\vec a$ and $\vec F = \frac{d\vec P}{dt}$ for constant mass systems. There's a big difference for variable mass systems. It makes a lot more sense to use $F=ma$ for variable mass systems.

In fact, even that isn't good enough for modeling the trajectory of a rocket that loses more than 80% of its mass and rotates by 90 degrees over the course of a few minutes. This is exactly the fate of rockets launched from the surface of the Earth to go into Earth orbit or beyond. Rockets aren't point masses. The center of mass of the rocket proper moves with respect to a rocket-fixed frame. This internal motion of the center of mass needs to be taken into account.

Accurately modeling the motion of a rocket is a non-trivial process, but that's a different question.

Comment: Your last statement sounds interesting. Would you mind kindly sharing the modelling of the motion with me?

Comment: @Benjamin -- That's a problem in some graduate level aerospace engineering texts. The answer is non-trivial; the derivation even less so.

Answer (score 0):

$F=ma$ is true only when the mass of the system is *fixed.* However, in your case where the spaceship is moving across space, the system is *losing* mass due to the *ejection of fuel out of itself.* For such cases, where the total mass of system is *varying,* we *cannot* use this version of *Newton's 2nd Law*. That version of the law that is written down in your question is the most general version. It is valid *even* if total mass of system is changing. That's why Newton himself believed in the power of his law in this version where we don't have to assume a fixed mass. (Though he did not live long enough to see its power in action.)

Comment: Ask any rocket navigation expert or rocket state propagation expert. They will almost inevitably use F=ma rather than F=dp/dt for the simple reason that F=ma is frame-invariant while F=dp/dt is frame-dependent.

Comment: @ David. That's true. If the time interval during which the motion of the rocket is concerned, is much less than the travel time between Earth and the destination, then the change in mass is negligible compared to the initial/final mass of the system. But let's not forget that from the launch of the original spaceship to its landing on the planet (destination) lots of parts (aside from its fuel) have been got rid of along the way. So, we never end up with the same mass with started with. You are right that we can use $F=ma$ but only instantaneously meaning we have to update the conditions.

Comment: You never end up with $F=dp/dt$, either. I can attest as a former rocket scientist: **Nobody** in this field uses $F=dp/dt$. $F=ma$ makes a lot more sense. It makes perfect sense for a rocket that looks like a point mass. For a rocket that doesn't look like a point mass (e.g., anything real), $F=ma$ still makes a lot more sense than does $F=dp/dt$.

Comment: WOW. Interesting. I could never imagine I will find a rocket scientist in here. Nice to meet you.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not get why system such as the rocket in space are defined as "variable mass" since the mass of the system is not varying.

It is because the "system" refers to particles that are still in the rocket, no to the whole system including the expelled exhaust gas.

This is often done when the point of the analysis is in describing and understanding motion of the rocket. In other situations the word "system" may refer to all particles that were originally part of the rocket; then mass of such system indeed does not change.

Answer (score 0):

Think of pushing a wagon full of sand down the road with a constant applied force.  $F=ma$ handles that just fine.  But now open a hole in the wagon so the sand slowly drains out as you push.  If you still push with a constant force the mass of the wagon and remaining sand in it decreases with time and of course you'll get it going faster in the end.

You might carry out two calculations.  If you define the system to be *just the wagon and the sand inside it*, then the mass of the system is varying and you need to use $F=dp/dt$ to find the final speed of the wagon.  It is not necessary for the mass to stay constant in any interval $dt$ to apply this.  It works in all cases.

On the other hand, you might define your system to be the wagon plus *all* the sand that started out inside it and track all of it even after some has seeped out of the cart. This system has a constant mass, but you still have to keep track of the fact that the pushing force acts on only some of the system mass.  I think it would be instructive to work out the total momentum of all the bits of this system for various "leak" rates of the sand.

Once a student of mine claimed that a rocket could never go faster than the speed of its own exhaust.  I had fun working out a proof that this is false by computing the total momentum of all the exhausted fuel and the empty rocket.  It's neat to see that enough total "backward" momentum of the fuel spent early on is present to allow for some fuel exhausted later in the flight to actually be headed in the "forward" direction along with the rocket payload.  The rocket does indeed end up going faster than the speed with which it shoots out its own exhaust.